# Building and importing EMF Compare 2

Tags: java, eclipse, emf, emf-compare

Im trying to use EMF Compare in a standalone Java application. In the Eclipse foruns, I was suggested to use the version in the git.

I cloned the repository. Then, I imported all projects in a workspace. I read that I just need the main EMF Compare lib, so I exported the project org.eclipse.emf.compare in a Deployable plugin and fragment, which I put inside the plugins folder in my default eclipse directory.

In my project, I can now import the org.eclipse.emf.compare, but when I run I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Sets
    at org.eclipse.emf.compare.scope.AbstractComparisonScope.<init>(AbstractComparisonScope.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.emf.compare.scope.FilterComparisonScope.<init>(FilterComparisonScope.java:63)
```

which is clearly because its not finding this guava google libs.

How should I proceed? Just have to change the way I generate the plugin, or should I generate a jar (and, in this case, how to export the google lib together?)

Thanks in advance,

Dusso

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am very late in answering (I do not follow the "emf" tag :s), but anyhow: the EMF Compare wiki explains how it can be used standalone, and what the minimal set of dependencies is (See this [FAQ entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF_Compare/FAQ#Can_EMF_Compare_be_used_standalone.3F)).

The first Orbit (Eclipse repository containing third-party dependencies) build that contained Guava 11 is [here](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20130118183705/) or you can use its [p2 update-site](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20130118183705/repository/) directly

Answer (score 0):

The first picture can be found in this website.
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anqll.png)
https://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/documentation/latest/FAQ.html

And the second picture is the way what I do.
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6ubL.png)